# Finding the WCHAN value

Tags: aix, ps, freeze

This is running on AIX version: 7, release: 2, on powerppc.

I have a process that is hung, and the output of `ps -ef -o THREAD` is:

```
USER      PID     PPID       TID ST  CP PRI SC    WCHAN        F     TT BND COMMAND
...
root 17105192 16646578         - A    0  60  1 f1000c01503c95d0   240001      -  -1 /bin/bash thecommand.sh
```

It's my understanding is that the value of `WCHAN` is related to what the process is waiting on, but I can't figure out what `f1000c01503c95d0` means.

- `/proc/17105192` doesn't have a `wchan` file
- `sudo procmap -X 17105192` shows:

  ```
  Start-ADD         End-ADD               SIZE MODE  PSIZ  TYPE       VSID             MAPPED OBJECT
  0                 10000000           262144K r--   m     KERTXT     10002             
  100000000         1001c8a4a            1826K r-x   s     MAINTEXT   830686           bash 
  1100009f5         1100213c0             130K rw-   sm    MAINDATA   881311           bash 
  1100213c0         110041400             128K rw-   sm    HEAP       881311            
  800200140000000   8002001400e5000       916K r--   sm    KER/LDR    8e9a9c            
  8fffffff0000000   900000000000000    262144K r--   s     KER/LDR    866ecc            
  900000000000d80   90000000048ac87      4647K r-x   m     SLIBTEXT   8c8019           /usr/lib/libc.a[shr_64.o] 
  9000000004b1220   9000000004b1c7e         2K r-x   m     SLIBTEXT   8c8019           /usr/lib/libcrypt.a[shr_64.o]
  ...
  ```

  And `1000c01503c95d0` isn't in any of those ranges.
- `sudo procfiles -n 17105192`shows:

  ```
  17105192 : /bin/bash thecommand.sh
    Current rlimit: 9223372036854775807 file descriptors
     0: S_IFIFO mode:00 dev:268435455,-1 ino:9352269 uid:0 gid:0 rdev:0,0
        O_RDONLY  name:Cannot be retrieved 
  ...
  ```

  There are 4 entries like this. "Cannot be retrieved" is suspicious. Searching for this node (`9352269`) with `ncheck` and `find` didn't find anything.

Is there a way to figure out more about what is going on here? Is there a way to verify what that `WCHAN` value is?

EDIT: Got a clue today. The parent process of the stuck processes are all sshd, and today I realized I was able to execute "ssh xxxxxx" but "ssh xxxxxx some_command" hung. When I tried "ssh -t xxxxxx some_command", I got a notice "NFS server someserver not responding still trying". I suspect that interactive shells are functioning, but non-interactive shells, like the ones running the processes that get locked, are getting hung up on the fact that one of our NFS servers was decommissioned and no one removed the mount from this server. I was able to execute non-interactive commands on other, nearly identical, servers, that did not have the mount. When I get permission to remove the mount, I'll update this question. Thank you everyone for your help and good questions. (Also, there's a strong possibility that I'm confusing "interactive shells" with "login shells", because I can never remember the difference)

Comment: Find the child-process(es) of this bash-process.

Comment: Running `ps l 17105192` may help a tiny bit; it will translate it to a "wait type" (ref:  https://groups.google.com/g/comp.unix.aix/c/6xTZRiXo-AY?pli=1). When I tried a simulation locally with a shell script reading from a pipe on a 7200-04 system, I got a WCHAN in the `f1000c015026....` range, which is close but slightly different from your `f1000c01503c...`, although as I create more of them, the number does increase. My best guess is a file reading from a socket or pipe. I get the "name: Cannot be retrieved" even if the files are *not* deleted.

Comment: Investigating the PPID of `16646578` could be interesting as well.

Comment: Sorry for the delay getting back to you; I haven't been able to come back to this problem this week. The PPID is sshd; another process is SSH'ing into the server and running a bash script, and the bash script is sticking someplace, for some reason. I tried "ps l <pid>" and it just says "EVENT". I tried kdb, "th -w WEVENT" and it lists the channel, but just says "pvthread+089A00 2202 bash     SLEEP 9A01F5 03C    0         0  F1000C01503C49D0" (the values probably changed; this is another instance of the problem).